# Problemas construyendo un diccionario para devolver un Queryset

Tags: python, django

Cuando quiero obtener un queryset filtrando segun varios parametros utilizo un diccionario, por ejemplo:

```
queryset = Actividad.objects.filter(**my_filter)
```

Donde `my_filter` ha sido construido de esta forma:

```
if nombre:
        my_filter["nombre"] = nombre

    if es_principal:
        my_filter["es_principal"] = es_principal

    if fecha_inicio:        
        my_filter["fecha_inicio"] = fecha_inicio
```

`nombre`, `es_principal`, `fecha_inicio` son campos de un modelo Actividad y vienen en los datos de un request.

Hasta el momento yo he filtrado cuando recibo valores exactamente iguales a los que tengo guardados en base de datos, por ejemplo buscan el nombre "Reunion" y en mi base de datos hay una actividad con ese mismo nombre.

Lo que quiero saber es como construir el diccionario para filtrar cuando el nombre contiene una o varias palabras, o cuando la fecha es mayor que la fecha enviada en el request. Trate de hacer lo siguiente pero no funciono:

```
my_filter["nombre"] = Q(nombre__like = datos["nombre"])

my_filter["fecha_inicio"] = Q(fecha_inicio__gte = datos["fecha_inicio"])
```

Comment: Porque no utilizas una libreria externa para hacer los filtros la libreria django-filter es simple de usar, y te ahorra todo esos problemas
http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/rest_framework.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los [lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) en Django son parseados internamente por lo que usándolos como llaves del diccionario debería funcionar:

```
my_filter["nombre__contains"] = datos["nombre"]

my_filter["fecha_inicio__gte"] = datos["fecha_inicio"]

queryset = Actividad.objects.filter(**my_filter)
```

Por cierto, no existe el lookup `__like`, para eso existen el [`__contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains) o el [`__icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains).

Comment: Vaya, yo habia probado el __like y tampoco me funcionaba, revisando tu sugerencia y la documentacion he podido construir el diccionario utilizando varios lookups. 

+100 a tu respuesta por salvarme el dia